# setInterval and clearInterval jquery - stackoverflow in IE7

Tags: jquery, setinterval, clearinterval, ie7.js

I have a jquery code that is moving up and down continuously a div containing a list with logos. The animation is repeating within a set interval and is all seems to be working as expected in Chrome, FireFox and IE 9 and 8 (no console errors).

However in IE7 I get 'script error' and the browser totally freezes... I think the setInterval and clearInterval are not working properly or i have messed up my code...

Here it is:

```
//<!------------------LOGOS ------------------>

// the automatic scroll start immediately
$(document).ready(function () { membersLogos() });

// set the interval after which to restart the animated scroll
$(function () {

  var intervalID;
  var resetTimer = function () {
    if (intervalID) { clearInterval(intervalID) };
    intervalID = setInterval(function () {
        membersLogos();
    }, 190000);
  };

});

// set the interval after which to restart the animated scroll

function membersLogos() {
  var pane = $('#mypane');

  if ($('#mypane').length) {
    pane.jScrollPane({
        animateScroll: true, //added
        animateDuration: 95000, //added - length each way in milliseconds
        stickToTop: true,
        //autoReinitialise: true,
        enableKeyboardNavigation: true
    });

    var api = pane.data('jsp');
    var logosHeight = parseInt($('#mypane .jspPane').height());

    //listen to the x-axis scrolling event
    pane.bind('jsp-scroll-y', function (event, pos_y, at_top, at_bottom) {
        //we're at the bottom now lets scroll back to the top
        if (at_bottom) {
            api.scrollToY(0);
            $(this).unbind(event); //added with edit
            $(this).bind('jsp-scroll-y', function (event, pos_y, at_top, at_bottom) {
                if (at_top) {
                    $(this).unbind(event);
                    api.scrollToY(logosHeight);
                }

            });

        }

    });

    //initial animate scroll to the top
    api.scrollToY(logosHeight);
  }
}
```

Any ideas or suggestions as what is wrong? Thanks in advance! 
Vik

Comment: do you call resetTimer function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've set your interval to *exactly* the sum of the two animations (190000 = 95000 * 2), I wouldn't be surprised if the interval function was being fired again before the animation completed, perhaps causing something to step on something else. It's easily checked: Just set your interval to 300000 or something and see if the problem goes away.

To avoid the possibility of having the interval fire again too soon, rather than using `setInterval` (which is almost always more trouble than it's worth), I'd see if `jScrollPane` offers you a completion callback when the animation is complete. If it does, use that completion callback to trigger the next animation. If it doesn't, I'd probably look to add it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I shall look into that... I'll rethink the jquery and come up with something better.